# user search - found but name does not match what's in AD

Tags: user-accounts

A user "Marketing Services" (mk@company.com) was added to a list permission about 4 weeks ago. The department decided to change the name to "Marketing Support" and AD was updated (3 weeks ago). Now I go back to the same list and delete the "Marketing Services" and do a user search for "marketing" or mk@company.com and it still showing the old name "Marketing Services" and "Marketing Support" does not show up in the list. By the way, this account is never imported into user profile db.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Does SharePoint maintains a copy of the user somewhere? If yes, may be i can delete this user from everywhere and re-add the user. btw, this particular user is not in user profile database. We do not import service accounts profile db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint keeps its own list of user information at the site level and it does not update automatically if the name is changed in AD. Best is to use powershell to sync the userlist with AD using the set-spuser command. It has a switch to sync a user. Set-SPUser -Identity domain\user -Web http://yourintranet -SyncFromAD will do the sync. You can then run get-spuser to confirm that all is updated. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607827.aspx

Comment: OMG. you saved my 2 weeks worth pain. Fixed and now shows the new display name. Thanks A BILLIONS.

Comment: I am glad I could help out :) Had this situation a couple of times before in the 2007 era and then had to fix everything with a console app and it was quite a pain. Gotta love Powershell :)